# How can one authenticate with AzAD while using Read-SqlTableData to read AzSQL tables

Tags: azure-sql-database, powershell, active-directory, access-control, ado.net

How should one specify the `User ID` while creating the `$sqlcc` object when using [Read-SqlTableData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/read-sqltabledata?view=sqlserver-ps) to read a table in [AzSQL with an Azure account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#azure-ad-admin-with-a-server-in-sql-database)?

```sql
$sqlcc = new-object ('System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection') "Data Source= <>.database.windows.net;User ID=<>@<>.onmicrosoft.com;Password=<>"
$sc    = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection') $sqlcc
$srv   = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $sc
$db    = $srv.Databases["TestDB"]                 
$table = $db.Tables["TestTable"]                
 
Read-SqlTableData -TopN 10 -InputObject $table
```

The code above is working for SQL ids but not for Azure ids. Specifying the `User ID` like `<>@<>.onmicrosoft.com` or `<User Objectid>@<Tenantid>` causes the `$srv` object to be blank.

[image]

Expecting screenshot or screenclip GIF that the answer code is working for an AzAD **user**id on AzSQL using [`Read-SqlTableData`](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1aa6fa4f-4fb3-48c6-b0a4-cc279090f0be/powershell-readwritesqltabledata-fails-connecting-to-azure-sql-database).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you set your connection context before performing any other action. From the documentation for [ServerConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection?view=sql-smo-160#properties), and [AuthenticationMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.sqlconnectioninfo.authenticationmethod?view=sql-smo-160):

> **Authentication**
> The authentication type of the connection

> **LoginSecure**
> If set to true, Windows integrate security is used and Login and Password are ignored. If not set, Sql Server Authentication is used. The authentication type of the connection

When choosing an authentication method, you must either choose `ActiveDirectoryIntegrated` or `ActiveDirectoryPassword`. `ActiveDirectoryIntegrated` will pick up the account executing the PowerShell and `ActiveDirectoryPassword` will allow you to specify the exact account, as in the examples below. If you use `ActiveDirectoryIntegrated` there is no need to include the lines that specify the `Login` and `Password`:

Example:

```
$srv = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') "<>.database.windows.net"

$srv.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = $false
$srv.ConnectionContext.Authentication = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.SqlConnectionInfo+AuthenticationMethod]::ActiveDirectoryPassword
$srv.ConnectionContext.Login = "***"
$srv.ConnectionContext.Password = "***"
$srv.ConnectionContext.Connect()

$db    = $srv.Databases["TestDB"]                 
$table = $db.Tables["TestTable"]                

Read-SqlTableData -TopN 10 -InputObject $table
```

It is highly recommended to use a credential object though, especially if you want to execute as the user who is running the PowerShell (beneficial for schedule tasks etc...):

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$srv.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = $false
$srv.ConnectionContext.Authentication = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.SqlConnectionInfo+AuthenticationMethod]::ActiveDirectoryPassword
$srv.ConnectionContext.Login = $cred.username
$srv.ConnectionContext.Password = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
$srv.ConnectionContext.Connect()
```

Also note, in the examples above I access the `ConnectionContext` directly from the `Server` object. I do this to remind myself that I am setting the *context*, you can also set the same properties directly from the `ServerConnection` like the example below:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$sc.LoginSecure = $false
$sc.Authentication = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.SqlConnectionInfo+AuthenticationMethod]::ActiveDirectoryPassword
$sc.Login = $cred.username
$sc.Password = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

Whether you choose to do it on the `ConnectionContext` or the `ServerConnection` is a matter of style, they are both actually the same instance of the same object.

***CAVEAT*** : I **cannot actually test** the above end-to-end as in my company we use multi-factor-authentication and so the above will not work with this enabled. However, this method will connect with SQL Server and AZ AD to verify that I need MFA.

Comment: I'm getting the same error while connecting with the first and the second method with the username specified in the email address format. `MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Connect" with "0" argument(s): "Failed to connect to server <>.database.windows.net." ` [See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCUib.png). I couldn't use the 3rd method since I'm not logged in as the same AzAD user. Are you able to use the first two methods to connect to AzSQL with an AzAD account?

Comment: @AyanMullick - I have updated my answer based on testing today.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I am able to set the `AuthenticationMethod` in `$srv`. However, I'm getting the same error using the first two methods as before.  `Failed to connect to server`  [See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcRaZ.png)

Comment: @AyanMullick then your issue is likely nothing to do with PowerShell and most likely be related to how you have configured your Azure SQL Database. Have you setup a Active Directory Admin on your instance? Did you create your logins with `EXTERNAL PROVIDER`?

Comment: Yes, I have [Provisioned Azure AD admin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#provision-azure-ad-admin-sql-database). [See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB0vw.png). However, I didn't create **logins with EXTERNAL Provider**

Comment: You need to create your logins with the `EXTERNAL PROVIDER` option, otherwise you cannot use AZ AD to authenticate your users.

Comment: Creating an external user and granting permissions didn't help either.

`CREATE USER [<>@<>.onmicrosoft.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
GRANT select, update, delete ON [dbo].[TestTable] TO [<>@<>.onmicrosoft.com];`

Answer (score 0):

I would visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication as there are a lot of different methods to connect depending on your circumstances.

But this might be a good example for you to follow. Ignore that it’s in c#. Pay special attention to the connectionString. Note the “Authentication” attribute. There are many other examples in the link above with other attributes to try:

```
// Use your own server, database, user ID, and password.
string ConnectionString = @"Server=demo.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Password; Database=testdb; User Id=user@domain.com; Password=***";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
conn.Open();
}
```

Comment: This method of connection, using a connection string, works if you want to run **TSQL** commands using `Invoke-Sqlcmd`. However, the method in the question is the only way to connect if one wants to run [native PowerShell queries](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1aa6fa4f-4fb3-48c6-b0a4-cc279090f0be/powershell-readwritesqltabledata-fails-connecting-to-azure-sql-database?forum=ssdsgetstarted). The SMO object is the only way to work with `Read-SQLTableData`.

Comment: The connection string formation is the issue I see. See the Authentication attribute. The question asked is showing how one might login using purely a sql login. The example I am showing above shows the difference, plus the link I provided shows many other connection strings.

Comment: The connection string creation process you mentioned works fine. It creates the connection, and one is able to use it with `Invoke-Sqlcmd` but not with `Read-SqlTableData`